# Firebase generating two different uid's for the same user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

Currently working on a React project that utilizes Firebase to store users. To make the user, I use createUserWithEmailAndPassword(). When the user is created in Firebase, it stores the user under an id that looks like -N4xrZ...

However, when I make a call to get the user's UID (through userCredential.user.uid), it returns a much longer one that looks like a typical UID generated by Firebase and that isn't the same as the user's parent id. Any ideas as to what this may be?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 1):

> It stores the user under an id that looks like -N4xrZ...

That's the expected behavior since you're using push(). This function generates a unique ID each time is called.

> When I make a call to get the user's UID (through userCredential.user.uid), it returns a much longer one that looks like a typical UID generated by Firebase and that isn't the same as the user's parent id.

The UID that comes from the authentication process, it's different than the one that is generated by push(). It's actually the same, each time you launch your app. So when you write data to the database, stop using push() and use the UID:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userCredential.user.uid).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
});
```

Comment: Hey Anon. Can I help you with other information?